# Create a deadzone within a jQuery clickable area

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, click, double-click

With [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [jQuery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/home) and one of the ui themes (I quite like [lightness](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#ffDefault=Trebuchet+MS,+Tahoma,+Verdana,+Arial,+sans-serif&fwDefault=bold&fsDefault=1.1em&cornerRadius=4px&bgColorHeader=f6a828&bgTextureHeader=12_gloss_wave.png&bgImgOpacityHeader=35&borderColorHeader=e78f08&fcHeader=ffffff&iconColorHeader=ffffff&bgColorContent=eeeeee&bgTextureContent=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityContent=100&borderColorContent=dddddd&fcContent=333333&iconColorContent=222222&bgColorDefault=f6f6f6&bgTextureDefault=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityDefault=100&borderColorDefault=cccccc&fcDefault=1c94c4&iconColorDefault=ef8c08&bgColorHover=fdf5ce&bgTextureHover=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityHover=100&borderColorHover=fbcb09&fcHover=c77405&iconColorHover=ef8c08&bgColorActive=ffffff&bgTextureActive=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityActive=65&borderColorActive=fbd850&fcActive=eb8f00&iconColorActive=ef8c08&bgColorHighlight=ffe45c&bgTextureHighlight=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHighlight=75&borderColorHighlight=fed22f&fcHighlight=363636&iconColorHighlight=228ef1&bgColorError=b81900&bgTextureError=08_diagonals_thick.png&bgImgOpacityError=18&borderColorError=cd0a0a&fcError=ffffff&iconColorError=ffd27a&bgColorOverlay=666666&bgTextureOverlay=08_diagonals_thick.png&bgImgOpacityOverlay=20&opacityOverlay=50&bgColorShadow=000000&bgTextureShadow=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityShadow=10&opacityShadow=20&thicknessShadow=5px&offsetTopShadow=-5px&offsetLeftShadow=-5px&cornerRadiusShadow=5px)) included

(bear with me, there is a question at the bottom which you can skip to if you like, just wanted to show how I got to where I am)

(sorry if there are any mistakes or bits I have missed out in the code, it does work, but was cutting up the code for ease of reading)

I started out with the standard [draggable + Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable) provide by the [jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/home) project:

```
// HTML
<div id="leftColumn">
<ul id="pageElements">
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="html">Html</li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="paragraph">Paragraph</li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="image">Image</li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="faq">FAQ</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="rightColumn">
    <ul id="pageItems"></ul>
</div>

// JavaScript Code
$("#pageItems").sortable({
    revert: true,
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    tolerance: 'pointer'
});
$("#pageElements li").draggable({
    connectToSortable: '#pageItems',
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
 });
```

Then I started to think well it would be useful to add a dblclick function to allow items to be shifted from one list to another without needing to drag, so I added this:

```
    $("#pageElements li").dblclick(function () {
        copythis(this);
    });

function copythis(elem) {
    var selected = $(elem).closest("li").clone();     
    $("#pageItems").append(selected).html();
}
```

Then I thought ok, now I want to dblclick on the pageItem and show a dialog for edit

so I added:

```
<div id="itemDialog"></div> 


$("#itemDialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal:true });
$("#pageItems li").live("dblclick", function () {
    openDialog(this);
});

function openDialog(elem) {
    $("#itemDialog").dialog('open');
}
```

Then I thought I want a button when I hover over an element, to allow me to delete, and I might as well have an edit route in there too:

```
var removeButton = '<span class="buttons"><span class="ui-edit ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" title="edit">Edit</span><span class="ui-remove ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" title="remove">Remove</span></span>';

$("#pageItems li").live("mouseenter", function () { $(this).append(addButton); }).live("mouseleave", function () { $(this).find(".buttons").remove(); });

    $(".ui-remove").live("click", function () { $(this).closest("li").remove(); });

    $(".ui-edit").live("click", function () {
        openDialog(this);
    });
```

So now it was quite functional, I wanted to then add an "add" button to the pageElement, so I would then have 3 options of drag, dblclick and a button click, so adding the code:

```
    var addButton = '<span class="buttons"><span class="ui-add ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e" title="Add">Add</span></span>';
```

used code from the pageItem li "live hover" again:

```
$("#pageElements li").live("mouseenter", function () { $(this).append(addButton); }).live("mouseleave", function () { $(this).find(".buttons").remove(); });

$(".ui-add").live("click", function () {
    copythis(this);
});
```

I amended the copythis function to allow for the inclusion of buttons:

```
function copythis(elem) {
    var selected = $(elem).closest("li").clone();
    selected.find(".buttons").remove();
    $("#pageItems").append(selected).html();
}
```

And this is where I am now and the problem I am currently working on.

If you dblclick the pageElement, that will copy the element (as expected).

If you click on the add button that will also copy a new element (as expected).

because the pageElement dblclick event is attached to the pageElement li tag and the add button click event is on a span tag nested inside that, if I click on the add button quickly sometimes I will get the dblclick event firing so adding more than one element to the pageItem list.

What I am looking to do is create a deadzone for the dblclick event which surrounds the add button item.

I am open to any ideas.

Cheers

Luke

Comment: it would be great if you could put it in http://jsfiddle.net/ for us to feel....

Comment: yer tiz: http://jsfiddle.net/bZ3qs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found an answer, probably not the best, but it works.

It involves defining a global variable:

```
var clicked = 0;
```

Then on the live event of the ui-add set the value to 1 and then set a timeout to delay the reset of the value back to 0:

```
    $(".ui-add").live("click", function () {
        clicked = 1;
        copythis(this);
        setTimeout(function () { clicked = 0;}, 100);
    });
```

So then on my pageElement dblclick function:

```
    $("#pageElements li").dblclick(function () {
        if (clicked == 0) {
            copythis(this);
        }
    });
```

Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's far from helpful, but I'd advise against listening to dblclick - it is a) works differently in different clients - and jquery doesn't mask all of it, b) you don't want your user to double click, it's complicated.